# Como migrar um sistema feito em C# utilizando ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-mvc-5

Bom dia! Sou novo no ambiente de programação e estou desenvolvendo um sistema o em C# utilizando Windows Forms. Futuramente pretendo fazer esse mesmo sistema em ASP.NET. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de aproveitar ao máximo o código já feito nos formulários e classes do projeto e migrá-los para o projeto em ASP.NET.

Comment: separe tudo que é forms do que é camada de negócio e dados

Comment: Aproveite também para extrair tudo que está em seu form, na programação orientada e botão e transporte essas fucionalidades para a camada de negócios tbm

Answer (score 1):

### Camadas

A solução que você está buscando é conhecida como arquitetura em camadas. Quando você separa seu sistema em camadas você está buscando algumas vantagens como independência e reuso. Qual a desvantagem principal? Mais trabalho para construir e mais "duplicidade" de código.

Um modelo de camadas popular é o modelo de 3 camadas, onde você tem a camada de apresentação, a camada de negócio e a camada de dados. Cada uma tem um objetivo bem definido e isso permite que você possa fazer a "troca" de uma camada sem precisar reescrever a outra. Perceba que essa é uma separação lógica e nem sempre significa uma separação física.

Em teoria, isso significa que cada camada será completamente independente e para que isso funcione você precisa trabalhar com o conceito de "interfaces". Isso quer dizer que a comunicação entre uma camada e outra precisa ser bem clara e definida para as duas pontas que vão se comunicar. Então você terá interfaces entre a camada de negócio e dados e outro conjunto entre a camada de apresentação e a de negócio.

Ter a camada de negócio não significa que você sempre vai ter regras de negócio aplicadas aos dados, mas é preciso que a comunicação entre a camada de apresentação e a de dados não ocorra diretamente, sem passar, mesmo que sem nenhuma alteração pela camada de negócio.

[Esse artigo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-modelo-multicamadas/5541) pode dar uma introdução nesse assunto.

No seu caso, você está criando a sua camada de apresentação usando o Windows Forms. As outras partes do sistema não deveriam ter nenhuma dependência dessa tecnologia, ou seja, se alguma classe de negócio ou de acesso a dados não puder ser retirada do projeto do Windows Forms e rodar em um projeto "Console", por exemplo, as suas camadas não estarão bem separadas.

De forma prática, trabalhar nas 3 camadas significa que você não teria nenhum código com regras de negócio ou com conexão a banco de dados dentro de formulários. Para que o formulário possa salvar os dados dele, precisaria passar esses dados através de uma interface conhecida pelas duas camadas. O mesmo deveria ocorrer entre a camada de negócio e a camada de dados. É muito comum também que os sistemas deixem acopladas a camada de negócio com a camada de dados quando não há uma preocupação em mudar de fornecedor de banco de dados, por exemplo, mas como disse no início, é sempre uma questão de escolha que vai te trazer vantagens e desvantagens.

Sobre a sua preocupação em reutilizar ao máximo o código que estiver nos formulários, se você já tiver separado essas partes acima, o próximo passo seria você escolher ou desenvolver uma tecnologia que pudesse gerar os seus formulários a partir de um conjunto de metadados. Essa arquitetura baseada em metadados permite que você passe a gerar os formulários a partir de algumas informações declarativas, algo parecido com o [XAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf). Você pode usar algo pronto ou construir um próprio. A ideia central é que a partir desses metadados você seria capaz de criar seus formulários tanto para Windows Forms, como para Web.